# Encrypted email test data set

Tags: email, testing, encryption, pgp, gnupg

I'm looking for a set of emails encrypted (and signed) by a variety of email clients in order to test a mail client. A downloadable mbox file along with test gpg keys would be ideal for this.

There seem to be a variety of ways that emails are encrypted (and signed), so getting all of them to work is difficult. And then you find another client that gets it wrong in a slightly different way, and you want to refactor your code but not break decryption of any emails you already support.

So does anyone know of such a dataset? Or failing that, a good list of the ways that different bits of software encrypt emails?

Comment: do you just mean PGP/GPG or also S/MIME?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Various clients sign and encrypt mail usually in two ways.

PGP/MIME : http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2015.txt and 
S/MIME : http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc5751.txt

You should be able to generate a good set of these using tools like mutt to script creation of these messages. I know this is not exactly the 'answer' but should help.